# GCC 4.5 and GCC 4.7 vector seems incompatible

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I'm creating the plugin for the proprietary application. The plugin is a DLL that later is loaded by the app and the app calls the functions defined in this DLL.

It seems like the app is compiled with TDM-GCC 4.5. So if I compile the plugin with the TDM-GCC 4.5 everything works as expected. If I compile the plugin with TDM-GCC 4.7, it starts crashing on vector assignment between the vector defined in application and in plugin.

Code in plugin:

```
vector<MyType*>* my_items;
void init(vector<MyType*>* items) {
    my_items = items
}
```

So the app loads the plugin DLL and calls the init(...) method, providing vector to plugin.

I'm quite new to C++ so I understood it as a difference in vector<...> implementation between GCC 4.7 and 4.5. Am I right?

Comment: Exporting functions with parameters or return values that are defined in a source code library is just going to end in tears and artificial couplings.

Comment: @JohnDibling I'm suspecting this. Just want to make sure the that app compiled with gcc 4.5 may be incompatible with library, compiled with gcc 4.7 IF they use the standard library vector<...> (or some other classes from standard library) to pass data between each other. Is it correct?

Comment: This is well-documented, too. If I remember correctly, `list` is also incompatible due to some ABI changes. (_"Vectors larger than 8 bytes in size are now by default aligned to an 8-byte boundary. This is an ABI change: code that makes explicit use of vector types may be incompatible with binary objects built with older versions of GCC."_)

Comment: The standard does not define an ABI, but rather an API. As long as your code complies with the standard, you can compile it with different compilers. Each compiler may yield a binary that is incompatible with the others (no ABI compatibility), but there is compatibility at the source code level